# Find two QnA maker link handler and assign each found regex an html <a> tag

Tags: regex

I want a regex for the following string:

```
For more:  [Click here](https://www.google.ca) and [click me](https://www.google.com)
```

For that My current regex is as follows.

`/\[.*\]\((((https?\:\/\/)|(www\.))(\S+))/ig`

Give me the regex with that I can find two different links in the same line.

Right now I am finding 1 combined regex for both of them.

Comment: The closing `]` overmatches as the preceding `.*` is greedy. Try `.*?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that we have URLs in `()`, which we can use an expression similar to, if that'd be the case:

```
\((https?[^\s]+)\)
```

with a capturing group, where our desired outputs are.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/HA0upr/1/)

For capturing the `[]`, we would just expand our expression:

```
(\[.+?])\((https?[^\s]+)\)      //$ sign removed
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/8XNeG5/1/)

Comment: I also want to detect [click here] and [click me]